# Where do upgrade packages go to when uploaded?

Tags: upgrade, update-packages

When you are upgrading Sitecore you install an upgrade package using the update installation wizard located here:
http://yourhost/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx

Where does it go to when it gets uploaded? I've looked on the file system but didn't find it. I assume it ends up on the database, if so where?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a package directory for the Update Wizard packages at the following path under the site root:

```
\sitecore\admin\Packages
```

Comment: thanks Michael. I was looking on the data folder but didn't bother checking within sitecore's folder. That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad I could help.